# Как получить значение из output?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

```
<form action="return false" oninput="work.value=inp_work.valueAsNumber">
<div class='inp_relax'><output for='inp_relax' name='work'>30</output></div>
<input id='relax_range' name='inp_work' type="range" min='1' max='60' 
value='30'/>
</form>
```

Как получить значение из тега Output?Это ползунок. Как можно реализовать получение значения. Функция `$().text` получает только данное значение в теге, а при передвижении ползунка значение не получает.

Данное чудо творю [тут](https://codepen.io/SeQwerMan/pen/jBMaRK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что надо  событие `change` отслеживать инпута

```js
function changeOutput(range) {
    $("[for='relax_range']").text(range);

}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#relax_range').on("change", function() {
       var  range = $(this).val();
       changeOutput(range);
       console.log(range);
  });
 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="return false" >
   <div class='inp_relax'><output for='relax_range' name='work'>30</output></div>
   <input id='relax_range' name='inp_work' type="range" min='1' max='60' value='30'/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Зачем брать значение из тега `output`, если его можно взять из `input`?

```js
function getvalue() {
  console.log(document.getElementById("relax_range").value);
}
```

```html
<form action="return false" oninput="work.value=inp_work.valueAsNumber">
  <div class='inp_relax'><output for='inp_relax' name='work'>30</output></div>
  <input id='relax_range' name='inp_work' type="range" min='1' max='60' value='30' />
</form>
<button onclick="getvalue()">Get Value</button>
```